Variable not updated by livewire when used as a style attribute value
I'm using Livewire 3 to dynamically update a progress bar, but the style="width" attribute doesn't refresh correctly with Livewire.
<div wire:poll class="relative h-5 w-full rounded-full bg-stroke dark:bg-strokedark">
    <div class="absolute left-0 h-full rounded-full bg-primary" style="width: {{ $campaign->progress }}%">
        <span class="absolute -right-4 bottom-full z-1 mb-2 inline-block rounded-sm bg-primary px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold text-white">
            <span class="absolute -bottom-1 left-1/2 -z-1 h-2 w-2 -translate-x-1/2 rotate-45 bg-primary"></span>
            {{ $campaign->progress }}%
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

But for the same variable, $campaign->progress, I got different value, for example :
<div wire:id="Ldkc3YGdR9488JMmLWFT" wire:poll="" class="relative h-5 w-full rounded-full bg-stroke dark:bg-strokedark">
    <div class="absolute left-0 h-full rounded-full bg-primary" style="width: 0%">
        <span class="absolute -right-4 bottom-full z-1 mb-2 inline-block rounded-sm bg-primary px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold text-white">
            <span class="absolute -bottom-1 left-1/2 -z-1 h-2 w-2 -translate-x-1/2 rotate-45 bg-primary"></span>
            90%
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

The first $campaign->progress, used as a style attribute, is never updated, unless I manually refresh the whole page, but the second occurence, displayed between the  works well.
Any idea why and how to fix it?
Thanks

I'm having this same issue, and it appears it's a Livewire bug introduced in version 3.5.7: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/8904
You can lock Livewire to 3.5.6 in composer.json until a fix is released:
"livewire/livewire": "3.5.6",
